# Use a direct proof to show that if $x\gt 1$ then $x^5 +x+1\gt 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

Use a direct proof to show that if $x\gt 1$ then $x^5 +x+1\gt 2$.

It's obvious that if  $x\gt 1$ then  $x+1\gt 2$ , also $x^5\gt0 \;as \;x\gt1\gt0$, thus $x^5+x+1\gt 2$.

Is it fine ?

I can't understand what do they mean by direct proof?

Comment: Yes, that proof is fine.

Comment: Is this a direct proof ?

Comment: Directly we get $x^5+x+1>1^5+1+1=3$, which is better.

Comment: I suppose by "direct" proof a proof which isn't a proof by contradiction is meant. Your proof clearly isn't by contradiction, so should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it is direct in the sense that you are showing that it is true without resorting to any roundabout arguments, or contradiction, or induction, or various theorems, etc.

Comment: Okie, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Since the derivative $f'(x)=5x^4+1$ is always positive, the function $f(x)=x^5+x+1$ is increasing over $\mathbb{R}$ and $x>1$ implies $f(x)>f(1)=3$.

Comment: Dat moment, when even using the derivative is a sledgehammer proof (see Dietrich's comment) but +1 I guess

Comment: If you want to be gentler you can use the increasingness of addition and multiplication. This is learned before the libidinal impulse.

Answer (score -1):

The function is monotone increasing for positive values. This is because addition and multiplication are increasing in either argument. Moreover the value at 1 is 3. The theorem follows.

Comment: The value at $1$ is $3$, but otherwise, yes.

Comment: @BrianTung do you know the Grothendieck prime?

Comment: I *might* have heard that story before?  I don't remember.  Anyway, a good one. :-)